# Get angle to land ballistic arc on target with fixed velocity projectile

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, game-physics

So I was trying to follow the code in this question to get a turret that can fire ballistic projectiles with a fixed starting velocity and no drag to a given point on a 3D surface.
[Find an angle to launch the projectile at to reach a specific point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376316/find-an-angle-to-launch-the-projectile-at-to-reach-a-specific-point)

But It's not quite working. The turret ends up aiming too high when the target is close, and too low when the target is further away. There is of course a specific distance at which it does hit the target but that distance is arbitrary, so that's not at all helpful to me.

The way the error scales makes me think I have a multiplication mistake, or am missing some multiplication or division, but I can't for the life of me figure out where I am going wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Code Below:

```
float CalculateAngle(float velocity)
{
    float gravity = -Physics.gravity.y;

    Vector3 modPos = target.position;
    if (modPos.x < 0) modPos.x -= 2 * modPos.x;
    if (modPos.y < 0) modPos.y -= 2 * modPos.y;
    if (modPos.z < 0) modPos.z -= 2 * modPos.z;
    modPos.x /= 10;
    modPos.y /= 10;
    modPos.z /= 10;
    
    float deltaX = modPos.x - FirePoint.position.x;
    float deltaZ = modPos.z - FirePoint.position.z;
    float deltaY = modPos.y - FirePoint.position.y;
    float horzDelta = Mathf.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaZ * deltaZ);

    float RHSFirstPart = (velocity * velocity) / (gravity * horzDelta);
    float RHSSecondPart = Mathf.Sqrt(((velocity * velocity) * ((velocity * velocity) - (2 * gravity * deltaY))/ (gravity * gravity * horzDelta * horzDelta)) - 1);
    float tanθ = RHSFirstPart - RHSSecondPart;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(tanθ, 1) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    if (angle < 0) return angle;
    return -angle;
}
```

[image: Close Range]

[image: Just Right]

[image: Long Range]

Edit 1:
Still struggling heavily with this. I just can't get the math to work. I went back to the original root of the knowledge here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56265/how-to-get-the-angle-needed-for-a-projectile-to-pass-through-a-given-point-for-t then wrote a function that did the exact equation given in the answers, copying the input values and everything. Except when I run it it fails, as one of the values that needs to be squared is negative which throws a NaN. I assume I am going wrong somewhere in my equation but I've gone over it a hundred times and I am not spotting the error. My code:

```
float CalculateAngle3(float velocity)
{
    float deltaX = 500;
    float deltaY = 20;
    float v = 100;
    float vSqr = v * v;
    float g = 9.81f * 9.81f;

    float a = vSqr * (vSqr - 2 * g * deltaY);
    float b = (g * g) * (deltaX * deltaX);
    float c = a / b - 1;
    float d = Mathf.Sqrt(c); //c is negitive causing an NaN
    float e = vSqr / g * deltaX;
    float tanθ = e - d;

    return tanθ;
}
```

Edit 2:
Gave up. This guy solved it so I am just going to use his logic instead
: P
https://www.forrestthewoods.com/blog/solving_ballistic_trajectories/

Using it like such:

```
Vector3 s0;
Vector3 s1;
if (fts.solve_ballistic_arc(FirePoint.position, bomb.StartingVelocity.z, target.position, -Physics.gravity.y, out s0, out s1) > 0)
{
    targetPosition = transform.position + s1;
    SafetyEnabled = false;
}
else
{
    //Don't fire if we don't have a solution
    SafetyEnabled = true;
}
```

I'm going to leave the question open for now since it's still technically not answered. I still don't know why the original implementation wasn't working.

Comment: Still struggling with this. The offset  is so weird I am having trouble figuring out how to correct for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your quadratic formula is incorrect (I do not know why you did not code a separate small function that solves the quadratic equation for any three given coefficients, to make your code more readable and less prone to errors)

```cs
float RHSFirstPart = velocity / (gravity * horzDelta);
float RHSSecondPart = Mathf.Sqrt(RHSFirstPart*RHSFirstPart - 2*RHSFirstPart*deltaY/horzDelta - 1);
float tanθ = RHSFirstPart - RHSSecondPart;
```

*A comment:* In most applications we do not really need the actual `angle` but the values of `cos(angle)` and `sin(angle)` because these are the components of the unit vector which usually is sought (just like in your case). So no need to use inverse trigonometry to find an actual number, which slows down calculations and is may introduce unnecessary round-off errors.

Comment: Hurm, tried replacing my lines with what you posted there, but that resulted in NaN errors, presumably from the equation generating a negative number causing the square root function to fail...